# Bootstrap 3 using affix to fixing navbar position to top when scrolling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, offset, navbar, affix

This is driving me nuts... This might be simple by I'm not hitting the nail: please give a hint :-)

I'm trying to play with Bootstrap 3 for a new layout for my site. I want the navbar to pin to the top of the screen when I scroll.

I got it working but the content below navbar shifts when the affix class kicks in. I can't find my way around it.

Comment: I figured it out. Adding padding the the element following the navbar. `#nav.affix + #mainContent { padding-top: 75px; }`

Answer (score 10):

There are two option either javascript or HTML5 `data-` attribute

**Via data attributes**
To easily add affix behavior to any element, just add data-spy="affix" to the element you want to spy on. Use offsets to define when to toggle the pinning of an element.

```
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
  ...
</div>
```

**Via JavaScript**
Call the affix plugin via JavaScript:

```
  $('#my-affix').affix({
    offset: {
      top: 100
    , bottom: function () {
        return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true))
      }
    }
  })
```

**DEMO**  http://jsfiddle.net/6P5sF/56/

reference http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix-examples